# G729 codec support in android

Tags: android, sip, rtp, codec

What is the best and most optimum way of having support of `G729` on android device ?

In my current application i have to use `G729` codec. I have search a lot, but couldn't get any library. Is there any way of using g729 ?

**EDIT:**

From where Can i buy those codec library and use it in my app for development ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have ended using  [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/features). It is very easy to build and use. Also they have added `G729` codec support which you can find in application settings.

[From here](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads)    you can checkout the latest source. Please read Readme file for build process.

Really good application to work with.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of G729 implementations if you google around for some.

There is the one in [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/jni/g729) you take and use. 
Here is another one I [found](http://www.codeforge.com/article/40693) which you could most likely convert to compile under android.

I have not seen any implementations in java tho, so you will most likely have to use the NDK to compile C/C++ source and access it from the android side.

The other fact you need to consider tho, is that G729 is NOT royalty free, so you need to pay royalty fees in your use of it.  See [here](http://www.sipro.com/FAQ-G-729.html) for details.

Comment: From the FAQ:
What kinds of products require a G.729 patent license agreement?

End-products using the G.729 technology require a G.729 patent license agreement. Qualifying end-products would typically include access devices, audio/video conferencing equipment, call center equipment, IP phones, IP/PBXs, media gateways, etc. Generic Microprocessors or Chipsets are excluded from this category.

Answer (score 1):

Probably ffmpeg supports that codec. There's a lot of examples on the net how to integrate ffmpeg into android (although this is, probably, not very easy)

Comment: ok, thats fine. and what about audio quality and performance of ffmpeg? is it open source ?

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg is open source and of fine quality. It's somewhat difficult to make it work with Android though because a lot of native code.